# How to use dollar signs/JQuery with Sublime Text 2 Snippets?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to create some code "Snippets" with Sublime Text2 and everything works fine except when I try and add jQuery code. Apparently any "Snippets" code that includes lines that begin with a `$` will simply not work. I couldn't find any answers online regarding this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Did you try escaping the `$` with a `\`?

For instance in PHP, the $GLOBALS snippet is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[\$GLOBALS['${1:variable}']${2: = }${3:something}${4:;}$0]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>globals</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>$GLOBALS['…']</description>
</snippet>
```

As you can see in `<content>`, $GLOBALS is expressed as \$GLOBALS. This is because $ is a symbol used for fields like ${1:variable}.

Comment: simply using \$ will results $

Answer (score 6):

Although not an 'answer' per se, my comment is more an example.

I had the same issue but for creating jQuery's shorthand `document.ready` function snippet in Sublime Text 2.

With your answer, I was able to make it work:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
    \$(function(){
      \$("$1").$2("$3");
     });
  ]]></content>
     <tabTrigger>jq</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Type `jq`, press `TAB` and you get this:

```
$(function(){
    $("|").("");
});
```

Notice the cursor is inside the first set of parenthesis, this is caused by the `$1` in the snippet. Once you've finished typing the value, press `TAB` again and the cursor will move to where the method goes, which is where the `$2` is in the snippet. Press `TAB` again and cursor moves to the second set of parenthesis where `$3` is.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thank you. New line before `\$` in `<![CDATA[\$` helped to make it work and is also ignored so you don't get an actual new line before snippet.